# Access writng to wrong row number

Tags: ms-access, vba

4150

```
NRrows = RSNonResourceCosts.RecordCount ' Number of Rows in Non Resource Table
NRCols = RSNonResourceCosts.Fields.Count ' Number of Fields in NonResource Table

Dim CL(1 To 10) As Integer ' This is to count "filled rows" when spreadsheet is filled
Dim Header(1 To 10) As String

'-----------
'Find the Headers (Taken from Actual Table and not predefined as original)

For Each Recordsetfieldx In RSNonResourceCosts.Fields
    If C > 0 Then
        Header(C) = Recordsetfieldx.Name
    End If
    C = C + 1
Next Recordsetfieldx
```

4170

```
R = 0
'Write to worksheet
RSNonResourceCosts.MoveFirst

Do Until RSNonResourceCosts.EOF
    For C = 1 To NRCols - 1
        FieldName = RSNonResourceCosts.Fields(C).Value

        If RSNonResourceCosts.Fields(Header(C)).Value <> "" Then
            CL(C) = CL(C) + 1
            WKS.Cells(200 + R, C) = RSNonResourceCosts.Fields(Header(C)).Value
        End If
    Next C

    RSNonResourceCosts.MoveNext
    R = R + 1
Loop
```

I attach code. Have solved part of original by defining Recordset. User can add column to Table. First part of code determines the headers. Second part determines values and writes to worksheet.  The new Rows are appearing first on the worksheet and in wrong column. I tried attaching worksheet but it looked awful.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) The order your records is the order they are in the recordset.  If you want them in a particular order, try sorting them (perhaps with an ORDER BY in the underlying SQL statement)

2) For the column issue:  In the first bit of code, I don't see where C is initialized, but keep in mind the Headers and Fields both start with an index of 0, so if you set Header(1) = the first field's header (index 0), but then copy the data in the fields without shifting the index value, it will shift everything over by one column.

As an added note, you might want to consider what happens when you have more than 10 columns.  Using fixed-length arrays means your code will break. You might want to read about using a dynamic array and ReDim.

Comment: Everything you mention has been taken into account, including Order By and limiting the number of columns. I'm completely baffled, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't yet feel like I have completely grasped the entirety of the problem yet, but let me take a stab at it. From what I do understand, data is being written from your record set into excel (good), but it is going into the 'wrong row' (question title) and the 'wrong column' (question text).

From what I see, I don't know the purpose of `FieldName = RSNonResourceCosts.Fields(C).Value`, but I want to make sure that you understand that `RSNonResourceCosts.Fields(C).Value` is not necessarily equivalent to `RSNonResourceCosts.Fields(Header(C)).Value`. More than that, you are likely missing at least one column altogether in your output, or at least skipping over it accidentally. rs.Fields(0).name is the first 'column' in a recordset, but it is completely ignored in your code. Perhaps this is intentional, maybe it is a key field or something useless to you, but it is important that you are making that distinction intentionally. But, since I don't see where your code populates the headers in your worksheet, I wonder if 'wrong column' means every record has been shifted a column and your last column is sitting empty. That, coupled with the dubious omission of C being initialized as 0 (not 1, or anything else) in your above code, makes me concerned that Header(3) could possibly by field(1), or field(4), or I don't know. That would certainly also confuse the columns in your output, or at least make dependence on FieldName frustrating.

Another thing, really a shot in the dark: NRrows. I have had issues before, depending on how I create my recordset, of not getting the correct record count the first time. And, if I base the population of a worksheet, array, etc., on the number of rows and the records relative position in that number, my records get all sorts of wacky. Maybe you did this already, but since it isn't shown, I recommend a `RSNonResourceCosts.movelast: RSNonResourceCosts.movefirst` line before you define NRrows, just to be sure.

And last, if I am way off base here... then you really are going to have to show us the spreadsheet, even if it isn't your most beautiful work. We all know that if it were, you wouldn't be asking about it here... so set your pride aside, and be more specific as well as show us what the output looks like and how it should look.